# how do I filter a bunyan log based on date?

Tags: node.js, bunyan

Got a bunyan log, here's a sample entry

```
[2016-05-31T15:38:47.889Z] FATAL: jklajsd-utilities/23399 on aaa.bbb.ccc.com: 
    0: {
      "code": "EADDRINUSE",
      "errno": "EADDRINUSE",
      "syscall": "listen",
      "address": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 5566
    }
```

OK I want to find all entries after that one:

```
bunyan /opt/aaa/.pm2/logs/cccc-out-15.log -c 'this.date >= new Date("2016-05-31T15:38:47.889Z")'
```

No results. Tried with `this.time` as well. The bunyan docs say that `time` is the right field but it doesn't work. `new Date("2016-05-31T15:38:47.889Z")'` is valid:

```
> new Date("2016-05-31T15:58:50.475Z")
Tue May 31 2016 08:58:50 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

The log filtering is certainly working:

```
$ bunyan /opt/aaa/.pm2/logs/cccc-out-15.log -c 'this.level === DEBUG ' |wc -l 
102455

$ bunyan /opt/aaa/.pm2/logs/cccc-out-15.log -c 'this.level === FATAL '|wc -l 
1679
```

Changing the year to 2015 didn't do anything.

So what am I doing wrong with date filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time in JSON is stored as a string. So you need to convert it before comparing.

```
bunyan /opt/aaa/.pm2/logs/cccc-out-15.log -c 'new Date(this.time) >= new Date("2016-05-31T15:38:47.889Z")'
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Filtering with `grep` prior to `bunyan`(as the other answer suggests) is just a workaround, but this is the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be to filter before calling bunyan:

`cat /opt/xyz/.pm2/logs/whiskey-tango-out-15.log  | grep "2016-10-11" | bunyan -o short`

Which produces:

```
[2016-10-11T22:33:08.836Z]  WARN: whiskey-tango/8828 on [redacted]: Post failed, retrying, count: 3
[2016-10-11T22:33:08.837Z]  WARN: whiskey-tango/8828 on [redacted]: Post failed, retrying, count: 2
[2016-10-11T22:33:08.837Z]  WARN: whiskey-tango/8828 on [redacted]: Post failed, retrying, count: 1
[2016-10-11T22:33:08.838Z]  WARN: whiskey-tango/8828 on [redacted]: Post failed, retrying, count: 3
[2016-10-11T22:33:08.838Z]  WARN: whiskey-tango/8828 on [redacted]: Post failed, retrying, count: 2
[2016-10-11T22:33:08.838Z]  WARN: whiskey-tango/8828 on [redacted]: Post failed, retrying, count: 2
[2016-10-11T22:33:08.839Z]  WARN: whiskey-tango/8828 on [redacted]: Post failed, retrying, count: 6
[2016-10-11T22:33:08.839Z]  WARN: whiskey-tango/8828 on [redacted]: Post failed, retrying, count: 3
```

Works for me. Seems like it should be doable with the bunyan command line though.

Comment: Note that you can use: pm2 logs --json to directly get log in json format